# EBS fault tolerance across Availability Zones

Tags: amazon-web-services

Reading through the description of EBS at https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/features/, I understand that EBS is replicated across servers of the same availability zone.

What happens if an entire AZ becomes inaccessible? Does EBS have a feature for replicating to other AZs in the same region?

Regards,
Yash

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you can't replicate EBS volumes to other AZ

However you can create [EBS snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html) that don't belong to any AZ because they are stored on S3. This can even be automated since AWS released [DLM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html) in july.